# Created Folder become file

Tags: android

I tried to create a file inside a folder inside Download folder. Im using emulator with API 31.

im already using this on manifest:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

and this

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

This is my code:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + File.separator
        + "DOWNLOAD"
        + File.separator
        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
        + File.separator);

if (!folder.exists()){
    folder.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
Log.i(TAG, "root: " +folder);

String stringPath = folder + "/" + eventNama + ".pdf";
File file = new File(
        folder.getPath()
);
if(file.exists()){
    file.delete();
}

file.createNewFile();
Log.i(TAG, ("file: " +stringPath));
```

This the log:

```
root: /storage/emulated/0/DOWNLOAD/Absensi Kegiatan Pemerintahan
file: /storage/emulated/0/DOWNLOAD/Absensi Kegiatan Pemerintahan/Kegiatan 2.pdf
```

The code create a file (that should be folder) without filename extension like this that cant be opened [image]

Comment: Yes indeed. You are not creating the folder and after that you use folder path to create a file with that folder name. It's your code that does it.

Comment: For instance: if a folder does not exist you should create it. Instead you are messing around with its parent.

Comment: `Log.i(TAG, ("file: " +stringPath));` You did not use stringPath. Better: `Log.i(TAG, ("file: " +file.getAbsolutePath()));`

Answer (score 1):

Because you have spaces in your folder name `Absensi Kegiatan Pemerintahan` 
to solve it replace:

```java
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + File.separator
        + "DOWNLOAD"
        + File.separator
        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
        + File.separator);
```

with

```java
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + File.separator
        + "DOWNLOAD"
        + File.separator
        + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name).replaceAll(" ", "%20")
        + File.separator);
```

Comment: I tried it, but "Absensi Kegiatan Pemerintahan" turn into "Absensi%20Kegiatan20Pemerintahan" and i tried to remove the spaces but that also only change the name to "AbsensiKegiatanPemerintahan" and still a file, not folder.